# Python extract all hrefs from a .txt file

Tags: python

I have a folder that contains thousands of raw html code. I would like to extract all the href from each page. What would be the fastest way to do that?

```
href="what_i_need_here"
```

Comment: You'll most likely want to use `os.listdir()` to get a list of files, and use Beautiful Soup to parse the html, then `soup.find_all("href")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    print (re.findall(r"href=\"(.+?)\"\n", ''.join(f.readlines())))
```

This would be what I guess might work, but there's no way to tell since you didn't provide any information. The regex used is `href="(.+?)"\n`. I read the content using `f.readlines()`, then combined it into a line to search using `''.join`. See if it works, or add examples of the text.

Comment: fun fact i didn't even have my python started up to try this, and normally whenever i write regex code it takes years to debug haha